# Lifetimes do not match method in trait

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, rocket

I have an asynchronous responder impl, but something is wrong with the lifetime of the objects. The code:

```
#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> Responder<'r, 'static> for LoginUser {
    async fn respond_to(self, _: &'r Request) -> response::Result<'static> {
        use LicensesStatus::*;

        let status = self.check_licenses().await;
        let json = serde_json::json!({"status": format!("{:?}", status)}).to_string();

        let response = Response::build()
            .sized_body(json.len(), Cursor::new(&json))
            .header(ContentType::JSON);

        match status {
            Valid => response.ok(),
            _ => response.status(Status::Conflict).ok()
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error[E0195]: lifetime parameters or bounds on method `respond_to` do not match the trait declaration
  --> src/views/login.rs:64:14
   |
64 |     async fn respond_to(self, _: &'r Request<'_>) -> response::Result<'static> {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetimes do not match method in trait
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you only checking the license in the responder? Shouldn't this happen earlier either in the handler or more preferably in a request guard?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Responder`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/response/trait.Responder.html) trait and its `respond_to` method are *not* `async`, so your implementation will not match the trait. You'll need to rethink your object such that the `LoginUser` already knows the license status, or move this logic into the handler itself.